# UWP In-Process Background Task not firing on mobile device (Win 10 Mobile)

Tags: mobile, process, background, uwp, background-task

Hello fellow developers,

for quite a time now I am fighting with an issue regarding **in-process** background tasks in **UWP**.

I am using a **time trigger** with **no conditions**. I tried different timespans (15, 30, 60). Access is requested in in the UI thread like so:

```
            BackgroundExecutionManager.RemoveAccess();
        // Überprüfen, ob Backgroundtasks erlaubt sind.
        var accessLevel = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
        if (accessLevel == BackgroundAccessStatus.DeniedBySystemPolicy ||
            accessLevel == BackgroundAccessStatus.DeniedByUser)
        {    
                ....
        }
```

The task is registered when the app is entering the background *(it is a data update that has to take place while the user is not using the app - otherwise there will be locks using the sqlite db)*. As soon as the the application is leaving the background, the task is unregistered and cancelled.

I know it seems likely that I did something wrong registering the background task or that the executed code is simply faulty.

**But:**

The whole construct is working perfectly on a Windows 10 Desktop device. It is even working on mobile devices if I run the background task via the app lifecycle in VS2017 *(using different devices, at least running anniversary update)*.

Sometimes the background task started *(I have log file)* but only about 10% of the code was executed.

I hope anyone of you has an idea for me.

Best regards

Kami

Comment: Background tasks should be lightweight to save battery life. `only about 10% of the code was executed`. The instructions is not accurate. You could log the time spent executing 10%  of the code. Is it  not more than the maximum time limit?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like I have to say goodbye to the background data update. Would have been to nice to be true. Thank you for your time.